# Segmentation loss function

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, semantic-segmentation

```
pred = model(x)['out']
loss_value=loss(pred, target.squeeze(1))
```

Hi, i am trying to train deeplabv3_resnet50 from pytorch for two classes (background and dog just to try make predictions better). As i understand pred gives us tensor with shape: (batch, num_classes, height, width). Now i need to choose a loss function: for example it will be torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss. It needs raw input, and only ONE segmentation mask with all classes with their values. So, why it's only one mask for two classes, what if there is more then 'two' classes? I thought it needs two masks, where background is 1 and dog 0, and vice versa. How CrossEntropyLoss works with this? Maybe [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGTKW.png) will help to explain it to me.

PS. I asked this question because [DiceBCELoss](https://www.kaggle.com/code/bigironsphere/loss-function-library-keras-pytorch/notebook) instead of one segmentation mask wants two as i understand

Comment: Please ask questions only once, there is an almost exact copy of this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72353078/semantic-segmentation-output

Answer (score 0):

When using [`nn.CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html), you are required to provide the labels in dense format, that is: ***not*** in one-hot-encoding format, which is what you've shown in your illustration for the target tensor. As a general rule of thumb `nn.CrossEntropyLoss` expects the target to have one dimension less than the prediction tensor. That is it contains exactly the same sizes for all dimensions but the one that contains the logits value corresponding to each class. In other words, the target tensor contains the label integer value where the prediction tensor has the probability maps. For example for 2D prediction, `prediction` tensor shape `(N, C, H, W)`, while `target` tensor shape is expected to be `(N, H, W)`.